# How to check non-existent fieldw in Httparty and Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, null, httparty

Being the xml result of a HttParty request

```
<people>
                <person>
                    <height>192</height>
                    <weight>80</weight>
                </person>
                <person>
                    <height>180</height>
                </person>
</people>
```

Some have entered their weight and height, some others only their height

So wen I do

```
entries.each do |item|

puts item["person"]["height"]
puts item["person"]["weight"]
end
```

It breaks when it finds the first person with no registered weight. I have tried using `.nil?` with no luck. How can I recognize non existent fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine item is an hash. So there are things you can do

```
person = item["person"]
if person.key?("weight")
  puts person["weight"] 
else
  puts "no weight"
end
```

or

```
person = item["person"]
puts person.fetch("weight", "no weight")
```

I suggest you to study Ruby hashes

Comment: Yep, so far ruby is not my main coding language